# Connect the SVG file to the content

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I use WordPress.

I want to make the bottom of the message `box` curved.

For this purpose, I placed an `SVG` file inside the body of the `box` and gave it the style `(position: absolute;)` and placed it at the bottom of the `box`.

In order for the `SVG` file not to be placed on the message `box`, I directed it outside the `box` so that it looks like the `box` and the `SVG` file are one.

My problem is when the body size of the whole page changes. In this case, a space is created between the `SVG` file and the body of the `box`.

I used `(@media )` and `(%)` but to no avail. That is, with the smallest change in screen size, two elements are separated.

Is there a way to keep these two elements from separating when the page is resized?

Or is there a way to make the `SVG` file stick to the body style?

```css
.box_main {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 3rem auto 5rem;
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
}

.box_main h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 25px 0 0;
}

.box_main p {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px 10px;
}

.box_main svg {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    fill: #eee;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box_main">

        <h2> Title </h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem repellendus eos vitae natus harum repudiandae
            impedit repellat veniam, hic recusandae!</p>

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 48">
            <path d="M0,0V48S131.13,7,243.67,7,424.36,45,585.43,45c133.43,0,174-20,214.57-26.81V0Z" />
        </svg>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `top: 100%` instead to position the top of svg at the bottom of the `.box_main` element.

Note: I noticed some micro white gaps between your svg and the grey box. Added a minus margin `margin-top: -1px` as a quick fix to eliminate them. You can fine tune it or redrawn your svg path to ensure the top part of your wavy shape is absolutely rectangluar.

```css
.box_main {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 3rem auto 5rem;
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
}

.box_main h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 25px 0 0;
}

.box_main p {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 20px 10px;
}

.box_main svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    fill: #eee;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box_main">

        <h2> Title </h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem repellendus eos vitae natus harum repudiandae
            impedit repellat veniam, hic recusandae!</p>

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 48">
            <path d="M0,0V48S131.13,7,243.67,7,424.36,45,585.43,45c133.43,0,174-20,214.57-26.81V0Z" />
        </svg>
        
    </div>
```